# Choose top two columns per group based on column median values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with 2 `id` groups and 5 `val` columns. I want to keep only 2 `val` columns which have the highest `median` values out of the 5 columns. For example, for `a` and `x`, `val3` and `val4` would be kept; for `a` and `y`, `val2` and `val3` would be kept and so on. All other `val` columns would then be given `NA` values.

```
  id1 id2 val1 val2  val3  val4 val5 val1_median val2_median val3_median val4_median val5_median
1   a   x   NA   NA 0.357 0.993   NA        1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
2   a   x   NA   NA 3.130 2.130   NA        1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
3   a   y   NA 3.68 2.990    NA   NA        3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
4   a   y   NA 5.99 6.190    NA   NA        3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
5   b   x   NA   NA 2.250 0.851   NA        2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
6   b   x   NA   NA 3.560 4.850   NA        2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
7   b   y   NA   NA    NA 3.600 3.12        2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
8   b   y   NA   NA    NA 2.640 3.50        2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
```

How do I go about doing this? Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  val1 = c(0.373546189257668, 2.18364332422208, 2.16437138758995,
           5.59528080213779, 1.32950777181536,
           3.17953161588198, 3.48742905242849, 2.73832470512922),
  val2 = c(0.94932754091116, 1.87825493706573, 3.6761525560408,
           5.98512403854922, 0.708267191273557,
           0.964831728704485, 4.61235997057159, 2.69339109611399),
  val3 = c(0.357355926158721, 3.12747953490738, 2.98559258268804,
           6.1891821233553, 2.24848514342358,
           3.96166791661305, 3.56199403579368, 0.748973009265844),
  val4 = c(0.993371937152378, 2.12751458469308, 2.00857588088462,
           4.12452841823852, 0.85135771670674,
           3.59747317608169, 4.84610860395753, 2.63553697778622),
  val5 = c(0.761217800817037, 2.12983828363918, 0.787311830761346,
           5.18028623883811, 0.935217818105011,
           3.1202182191708, 4.58745442441237, 3.50150045358676),
  id1 = as.factor(c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")),
  id2 = as.factor(c("x", "x", "y", "y", "x", "y", "x", "y"))
)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), funs(median = median(., na.rm = TRUE)))
df1
  id1   id2    val1  val2  val3  val4  val5 val1_median val2_median val3_median val4_median val5_median
  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 a     x     0.374 0.949 0.357 0.993 0.761        1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
2 a     x     2.18  1.88  3.13  2.13  2.13         1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
3 a     y     2.16  3.68  2.99  2.01  0.787        3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
4 a     y     5.60  5.99  6.19  4.12  5.18         3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
5 b     x     1.33  0.708 2.25  0.851 0.935        2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
6 b     x     3.49  4.61  3.56  4.85  4.59         2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
7 b     y     3.18  0.965 3.96  3.60  3.12         2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
8 b     y     2.74  2.69  0.749 2.64  3.50         2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
```

Comment: Please add your desired output.

Comment: Added desired output as suggested. Thank you @tmfmnk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your `df1` we can separate median and value columns. For all the median columns we find all the values which we want to turn into `NA`. So we `order` `df1` rowwise and get all the row index except top 2. Create a row-column matrix and change the values to `NA`.

```
med_cols <- grep("median$", names(df1))
val_cols <- grep("^val", names(df1))

df1[val_cols][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), 
  c(t(apply(df1[med_cols], 1, order))[, 1:(length(med_cols) - 2)]))] <- NA

#   val1  val2   val3   val4  val5 id1   id2   val1_median val2_median val3_median val4_median val5_median
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#1    NA NA     0.357  0.993 NA    a     x            1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
#2    NA NA     3.13   2.13  NA    a     x            1.28        1.41        1.74        1.56        1.45
#3    NA  3.68  2.99  NA     NA    a     y            3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
#4    NA  5.99  6.19  NA     NA    a     y            3.88        4.83        4.59        3.07        2.98
#5    NA NA     2.25   0.851 NA    b     x            2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
#6    NA NA    NA      3.60   3.12 b     y            2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
#7    NA NA     3.56   4.85  NA    b     x            2.41        2.66        2.91        2.85        2.76
#8    NA NA    NA      2.64   3.50 b     y            2.96        1.83        2.36        3.12        3.31
```

Comment: Oh, I see I did almost the same as you. Should I remove my post?

Comment: @tmfmnk yes, almost the same but I think OP changed their requirement.

Comment: Thank you both. This is not exactly what I want. Kindly see my updated desired output

Comment: @RonakShah: That did it. Thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the median by group:

```
df %>% group_by(id1, id2) %>% summarise_at(vars(starts_with("val")), median)
```

Comment: I already did that in my question. Kindly see my desired output.